# Superset 3.0.0 404 on GET and DELETE on tableschemaview for Admin role user with all permissions on TableSchemaView

Tags: apache-superset, duckdb

I am the admin for Superset 3.0.0. When in SQL Lab I click on a table (from DuckDB), I get an error message at the bottom right corner that says "An error occurred while fetching table metadata" and on selecting two tables "An error occurred while removing the table schema. Please contact your administrator."

The logs show:

```
404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
superset | 192.168.176.1 - - [15/Dec/2023:18:59:38 +0000] "GET /tableschemaview/dtvBbokbR HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-"
```

^ Same 404 error for DELETE on tableschemaview

How to reproduce the bug
This bug did not exist earlier for me and I could see a preview of the schema of the table I was requesting.

- Go to 'SQL Lab, click on database (select a DuckDB database that has create table, view, DML, exploration' enabled
- Click on 'schema duck.main'
- Click on any table > "An error occurred while fetching table metadata". Remove table from the selection > "An error occurred while removing the table schema. Please contact your administrator." The logs show 404 errors on tableschemaview for GET and DELETE

**Expected results**: The table schema preview loads in the left pane of the SQL Lab

**Actual results**: Error box in bottom right corner

**Environment**:

- browser type and version: MS Edge Version 120.0.2210.77 (Official
  build) (64-bit)
- Superset version: 3.0.0
- python version: from docker image superset:3.0.0
- Any feature flags active: I have tried removing all caching and features from `superset_config.py` but the problem remains

**Checklist**:

[.] I have checked the superset logs for python stacktraces and included it here as text if there are any

[.] I have reproduced the issue with at least the latest released version of superset: 3.0.2

[.] I have checked the issue tracker for the same issue and I haven't found one similar.

**Additional context**:

- Superset is running with built in google OAuth behind a nginx reverse proxy
- Queries, dashboard, charts, SQL Lab is working fine. This error is thrown only in SQL Lab